# angular.injector - can't find custom (app-related) services

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a angular application. I start it and I open the chrome dev tools console and start typing.

I want to do some `$injector.get(...)`, to play with my services and factories in console. But I'm not in a DI context, so... `$injector` is the same as `angular.injector()`, right? So I type `angular.injector().get('MyModel')` and I get

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: MyModelProvider <- MyModel
```

Well... why does angular injector can't find the model that I have declared with:

```
MyModule.service('MyModel', MyModel);
```

and I'm sure it works, because when I click out some things in the app, the model gets used and calls the API correctly.

Moreover, if I execute `angular.injector().get('$attrs')` or angular.injector().get('$scope') or whatever, I get the same errors. So I can see that I can't use injector this way.

What am I doing wrong? Or is there something wrong with my app configuration?

More or less, what I want to do is to retrieve a service or a factory or whatever from angular in the console (when the app is already loaded) to play with those DI-components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
angular.element(document.body).injector().get('MyModel')
```

For any DOM element you can do this:

- `angular.element(domElement).scope()` to get the current scope for the element
- `angular.element(domElement).injector()` to get the current app injector
- `angular.element(domElement).controller()` to get a hold of the `ng-controller` instance.

Comment: Well, this one worked, but why does `angular.element(document.body).injector().get('$attrs')` still fail? What changes inside angular if I change `injector()` to `injector([mod1, mod2, ...])`? Some people advise to do so, but it doesn't work always.